# Idera ER-Studio: How to use "User Defined Properties" on Columns and Tables?

Tags: extended-properties, scd2

How to define "User Defined Properties" that can show up on the Metadata Export, in Idera ER-Studio? We are trying to include properties such as Business-Key identifier, SCD identifiers and a few other similar stuff. While exporting Model Metadata it gives options of displaying these UDPs, but nowhere in the tool can I find how to set those up.

Just as a background, we are setting up a new data-warehouse which will be loaded using a metadata framework. Our idea is to maintain the data model architecture in ER-Studio along with these sorts of custom tags and load them directly on to the MDF.

One potential place I could see was "Extended Properties" on both column and table level where I can define custom property names and their values, but they don't show up on the UDP section of the metadata-export. Moreover, neither do they seem to reflect in the macros, nor can they be set or updated using macros.

ER-Studio's help guide doesn't contain any info on UDPs. There aren't any prior discussions on the internet on this topic either.